# Null in relationship belongs to in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have table `products` and `job_statuses` and there is a relation between them in migration products:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('job_status_id')->index()->nullable();
$table->foreign('job_status_id')->references('id')->on('job_statuses')->onDelete('set null');
```

In Product model:

```
public function job()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(JobStatus::class);
}
```

in blade dd :

```
 @foreach ($products as $product)

     @dd($product->job)

 @endforeach
```

I got `null`

The weird thing that when I do the same way but in tinker the relation is worked!

Comment: welcome to so, I would suggest if you can show the controller method which sends the products data to view

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the foreign key in relationship. by default laravel assumes the foreign key as relationname_primarykey of related table. in your case the relationship name is job but the foreign key is job_status_id. so the relationship is not biulding. change like

```
public function job()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(JobStatus::class, 'job_status_id');
}
```

and a note. as you are using nullable you should check for relationship existence first.

Comment: Still get null even job_status_id in relation and make if| and I CHECK database and there is a id in (job_status_id)

Comment: how are you sending data from controller?? using eloquent or query builder??

Comment: in your question, in blade you are using a foreach loop for the variable products. how are you generating this variable??

Comment: simple  ( $products = Product::get(); )

Comment: can you eager load the relationship and check with dd??

Comment: The wired thing I called the relation in tinker and worked! but in reality in gives me  null !!!

Comment: something you are missing. can you add the controller code and other necessary code in your question??

Comment: Like what? can I give you ZOOM meeting to just see?

Comment: just update your question with the respective code.